# Can I bundle the Bonjour installer with my application?

Tags: bonjour

I'm thinking about using Bonjour in my Windows application. My application would need to bundle the Bonjour.msi setup file as a redistribute, to install it on the users' computers.

But while reading the wiki for Bonjour, I noticed that developers need a license agreement simply to be able to add the redistributable:

> Bonjour is released under a terms-of-limited-use license by Apple. It is freeware for clients, though developers and software companies who wish to redistribute it as part of a software package or use the Bonjour logo may need a licensing agreement. The source code for mDNSResponder is available under the Apache License.

I just want to bundle the redistributable in my installer, so my app can find peers in the local network. Have other people done that, and is it allowed by whatever license Apple has for it?

Comment: I know that, but unfortunately, that's one of those questions that would seriously save me time and trouble, and would be hugely helpful, so I have to ask. Hopefully, someone will answer in a comment before my question gets closed :) Besides, that's hardly legal advice, I'm just asking if anyone knows if this library is free to redistribute or not.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about use of software requiring a license from the vendor, and should be addressed to the vendor. It is not a programming question ini accordance with the guidelines specified in [help].

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is allowed as long as you follow their bundling/logo agreements.  [More info on Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/softwarelicensing/agreements/bonjour.php#bonjourwin).